# Rearrange children orger in Javascript doesn't work multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code to move the childs order in an element. When I click once, it works fine, but when I click multiple times, it only works every 2nd or 3rd time.

```js
const prevP = () => {
    const pList = document.getElementById("project-list")

    const firstProject = pList.firstChild;

    const lastProject = pList.lastChild;

    pList.insertBefore(lastProject, firstProject);
}

const nextP = () => {
    console.log("next");
    const pList = document.getElementById("project-list")

    const firstProject = pList.firstChild;

    let lastProject = pList.lastChild;

    pList.insertBefore(firstProject, lastProject);
}
```

```html
<span class="material-icons md-48 close icon-btn" onclick="prevP()"
            >navigate_before</span
          >
          <div class="project-list" id="project-list">
            <div class="project">
              <img href="protfolio" alt="" />
              <p>My Portfolio 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project">
              <img href="protfolio" alt="" />
              <p>My Portfolio 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project">
              <img href="protfolio" alt="" />
              <p>My Portfolio 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project">
              <img href="protfolio" alt="" />
              <p>My Portfolio 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project">
              <img href="protfolio" alt="" />
              <p>My Portfolio 5</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="material-icons md-48 close icon-btn" onclick="nextP()"
            >navigate_next</span
          >
```

I also realised that sometimes the code messes up the order of the elements when using both buttons, and I have no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of that behaviour is that you use `firstChild` and `lastChild`. These may select text nodes with just some white space. Change these to `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild`.

Secondly, the "Next" action should not insert the first element *before* the last element, but *after* it. For that you can use the method `appendChild`:

```
    pList.appendChild(firstProject);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to add transitions to that?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to work with offsets so that a transition kicks in, and only perform the DOM move when the transition is complete. For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123525/using-jquery-to-re-order-and-animate-list-items) is one that uses jQuery.